# Mayavi- Scale a surface without translating it

Tags: scale, mayavi

im wondering if its possible to scale an surface-object in mayavi without moving/translating it.

So far I just use the surface.actor.actor.scale property and assign a 3D-vector to it. However, the surface does not Keep its original Position but the scaling is carried out with respect to the origin (0,0,0) - That's why it seems like the surface moves...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the actor's origin to the center of mass of the surface?

Comment: Well, I guess I could do that.. but for this purpose I first have to calculate the Center of mass.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to do that then what sort of result are you expecting? The surface *will* move, because it is not possible for a surface at a larger scale to occupy the same points as a smaller surface. Hence, the surface will "move". Your question is meaningful in the sense that the surface can be scaled without translation with respect to some centroid. Isn't that what you want? In principle the choice of centroid depends on the visualization. But for most purposes I would choose the midpoint of the X,Y,Z ranges of the surface, which is easy to calculate.

Comment: ok, I did calculate the centroid and used both the Position as well as the origin property of the actor to move the surface. However, the surface is still translated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked about the `origin` attribute on the vtk actors, I was genuinely inquiring as to what had been tried. I have played a little bit with that but I don't know all the details of how vtk actors decide to position themselves, it is very complicated and mathy and I find it mostly easier to just hack it and do the math manually (at least when the math is simple).

Here is a much simpler solution. Note, it is not necessarily the best solution. There may be a much cleaner solution that I have just not found.

The basic idea of this solution is really simple: scrape the x,y,z coordinates of the surface vertices, apply the correct linear translation to these points, and feed them back to the source.

```
surf = mlab.surf(*args) # somehow generate a surface
xc,yc,zc = centroid() #somehow determine the x,y,z coordinates to stabilize towards
scale_factor = 2.8

tx,ty,tz = surf.mlab_source.x, surf.mlab_source.y, surf.mlab_source.z
aff = np.eye(4)*scale_factor
aff[:,3] = (-xc,-yc,-zc,1)

dat = np.array(zip(tx,ty,tz,np.ones(len(tx))))
surf.mlab_source.x, surf.mlab_source.y, surf.mlab_source.z,_ = np.dot(aff, dat.T)
```